# Automatically check Null checkbox in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on SSRS report, Below I have set allow null value for date selection. It's working fine while running it on report builder but not web page. does anyone have idea what can be the issue?

[image]

I wanted to check the null checkbox if there is no value in date selection.

Please help!!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why isn't it working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: there is no error but don't know why it is not working on web page. checked in all browser...

Comment: When there is no date selected, you want that checkbox to be checked automatically?

Comment: yes correct! how can I please help....

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115255/ssrs-parameters-toggle-a-parameters-null-checkbox-depending-on-value-other-pa

Comment: I checked but it's working in report builder but not in web page. how can i solve?

Comment: You can't like the person said: "*The checkbox for a parameter to allow NULLs can only be set at design-time. You* ***can't*** *have it checked/unchecked depending on other parameters or user action.*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. Need to manually check report properties from reporting service.

[image]